# Android net-core Dependency module

Tags: android, asp.net-core, .net-core

Error :
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration

> Could not find in.netcore.smartechfcm:smartech-fcm:1.1.6.

implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.6'

I have tried upgrade and downgrade the version of dependency but there is same above error is coming.
plz resolve the issue help me out from this issues..

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether you are using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code IDE? What type of Asp.Net Core project you are developing? Please inform us what exact dependency you have tried to add to your project and how you add it? It could help us better understand the issue.

Comment: we are using andriod studio

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT plz help to resolve the issue.